# My application keeps loading after trying to clear FilesystemCache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony4

I have an application that runs on **Symfony 4**. I use the filesystem cache component. I wanted to create a function that empties it, but unfortunately, my entire application is now broken. All pages will continue to load forever.

[image]

Below the script that I have executed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use App\Entity\Instelling;

class AdminInstellingController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/beheer/cache-clear")
     */
    public function clearCache()
    {
        $cache = new FilesystemCache();
        $cache->clear();

        $this->addFlash("success", "De <strong>CRM DataServer</strong> cache is succesvol geleegd.");
       // return $this->redirect('/beheer/dashboard');
    }
}
```

I have deleted my var/cache folder, my temp folder where this cache is stored by default (*sys_get_temp_dir*), reinstalled my vendors, emptied my cookies and cache and restarted my computer. Nothing works at all and the application keeps loading. What do I have to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good approach to clear cache from inside a controller.
You should create a command and clear cache through command-line

```
php bin/console make:command app:clear-filesystem-cache
```

and write cache clear function in it

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

    $cache = new FilesystemCache();
    $cache->clear();

    $io->success('De CRM DataServer cache is succesvol geleegd.');

    return 0;
}
```

Then clear cache using this command.

```
php bin/console app:clear-filesystem-cache
```

If you want to achieve this in controller then increase `max-execution-time` in php.ini to more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to implement console command, but for quick test can simply change time limit direct in controller vs. global change in php.ini:

```
public function clearCache()
{
  //  set_time_limit ( int $seconds ) : bool
  set_time_limit(300);
  //...
}
```